# SQL Function thrown error Maximum Limit Error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [PtOrderDetailID]
    (@OrderDetail_ID INT)  
RETURNS INT  
AS  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @OriginalOrderDetail_ID AS INT  
    SET @OriginalOrderDetail_ID = @OrderDetail_ID  

    IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TRRawDetail OD (NOLOCK) 
        WHERE OD.OrderDetail_ID = @OriginalOrderDetail_ID 
          AND OD.RelatedOrderDetail_ID IS NOT NULL 
          AND OD.RelatedOrderDetail_ID <> 0) > 0  
        SET @OriginalOrderDetail_ID = (SELECT TOP 1 OD.RelatedOrderDetail_ID 
                                       FROM TRRawDetail OD (NOLOCK)  
                                       WHERE OD.OrderDetail_ID = @OriginalOrderDetail_ID 
                                         AND OD.RelatedOrderDetail_ID IS NOT NULL 
                                         AND OD.RelatedOrderDetail_ID <> 0)  

    SET @OriginalOrderDetail_ID = PtOrderDetailID(@OriginalOrderDetail_ID)  

    RETURN @OriginalOrderDetail_ID;  
END
GO
```

The function is called from a stored procedure, but throws "Maximum Limit (32)" error. Please help to resolve this issue

> Msg 217, Level 16, State 1, Line 200
>   Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)

I thought this the function called inside the nested recursive calling due to this. How to resolve this?

Comment: Could you post the code of stored procedure?

Comment: Inside your function, you're calling that same function again: `SET @OriginalOrderDetail_ID = PtOrderDetailID(@OriginalOrderDetail_ID)` - this will cause a loop, that ends with the error message you're getting ...

Comment: yes @marc_s.how to resolve it

Comment: Are you missing an `else` to control which assignment to `@OriginalOrderDetail_ID` executes? Aside; When checking for the existence of one or more rows it is more efficient to use [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) rather than getting an exact [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) and then just checking if it is greater than zero.

Comment: Aside: As a rule `top` should have an associated `order by`.

Comment: Actually the orderdetail_ID and originalorderdetail_ID some ID same . so its called recursively.but i need to correct the data or function

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your function, it seems you are calling  it recursively even if there is no relatedorder_detail, in which case it will keep calling recursively using the initially passed OrderDetail_ID . You should be putting the recursive call within the IF block

```
ALTER FUNCTION [PtOrderDetailID]
    (@OrderDetail_ID INT)  
RETURNS INT  
AS  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @OriginalOrderDetail_ID AS INT  
    SET @OriginalOrderDetail_ID = @OrderDetail_ID  

    IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM TRRawDetail OD (NOLOCK) 
        WHERE OD.OrderDetail_ID = @OriginalOrderDetail_ID 
          AND OD.RelatedOrderDetail_ID IS NOT NULL 
          AND OD.RelatedOrderDetail_ID <> 0) > 0  
      BEGIN
        SET @OriginalOrderDetail_ID = (SELECT TOP 1 OD.RelatedOrderDetail_ID 
                                       FROM TRRawDetail OD (NOLOCK)  
                                       WHERE OD.OrderDetail_ID = @OriginalOrderDetail_ID 
                                         AND OD.RelatedOrderDetail_ID IS NOT NULL 
                                         AND OD.RelatedOrderDetail_ID <> 0)  

    SET @OriginalOrderDetail_ID = PtOrderDetailID(@OriginalOrderDetail_ID)  
    END
    RETURN @OriginalOrderDetail_ID;  
END
GO
```